# creating a row div every two items using Razor

Tags: razor

The following code works if each row has two items but it breaks if the last row only has one item. How would I get this to work to display a row div for every 1 or 2 items?

```
@{
   var count = 0;
   var rowCreate = false;
}

if (count == 0 || (count % 2 == 0))
{
    rowCreate = false;
    @Html.Raw("<div class='row'>");
}
else { 
    rowCreate = true;
}

<div class="col-md-6">
    Content
</div>

if (rowCreate) {
   @Html.Raw("</div>");
}

count++;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (rowCreate)
                {
                    @Html.Raw("</div>");
                }

                count++;

                if (CurrentPage.AncestorOrSelf(2).Children.First("Name == \"" + page + "\"").Children.Count() == count && count % 2 != 0)
                {
                    @Html.Raw("</div>");
                }
```